# Is it okay to style a input elements like type = text with height and width, rather than using size attribute?

Tags: html, css

My question says it all. If we specify in `css` the width and height of `textarea` or `text` type `form` elements and don't use `rows` and `cols` property and `size` attribute respectively. Does it really matter? I would like to know are there any performance degradation's in the same on using on over the other.

Comment: Performance does not matter. Forget about it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`width` and `height` will override the values set for any sizing attributes, be it `size` or `col` and `row` (See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/Bmp65/). I would highly recommend setting the dimensions using `width` and `height`, since setting the `size` or `col` and `row` will lead to cross-browser inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

setting height on input text is very dangerous!

on some systems the text may not be fully visible in the Y axis

safe solution is setting line-height instead of height

in textareas there is no problem (unless you want a textarea of one single row)

it is preferred to use cols rows and size attrbutes for backward compatibility, but if your audience are users with a modern browser css will be sufficient

HTH

edit:

```
<input type="text" style="font-size:20px;line-height:1;height:20px;"
value="ASDASDASD">
```

in firefox, "zoom text only" under View > Zoom
then zoom to 150%
this may happen on older firefox users, IE6 and probably 7 users (not sure)
where zoom applies only to text

in plus some systems have a native padding inside the textbox that you can't override,
a space used for focus rings/highlight outline, and it occupy some space that is included in the css "height"

if you remove height:20px; theres no problem at all I guess,

Comment: do u have any link where it says it is dangerous

Comment: Please write complete, coherent paragraphs, and back up your seemingly loose claims.

Answer (score 2):

The performance does not depend on the `width` and `height` properties itself, but on the way you specify your element in the stylesheet. For best results, reference the textbox by ID.
For instance

```
#thetextbox {width:10em; height:2em}
```

is faster than

```
form fieldset:nth-child(3) input[type="text"] {width:10em; height:2em}
```

Comment: "The performance does not depend on the width and height properties itself" How do you know this?

Comment: Because these elements have a specific default width and height already; these properties just get replaces with the calculated values from the CSS. Just like assigning attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to use specify the width and height in css instead of using `cols` and `rows`.  `cols` and `rows` really aren't good if you need the textarea to fit in a certain space, so using css is better.

Answer (score 0):

if you use rows and col in your design , your page dose not displays good  in  different browser.using Css its better.

Answer (score 0):

## Use CSS!

The `rows`, `cols`, and `size` html attributes exist purely for style purposes.

In my opinion, you should leave the styling to CSS, so that you have separation of content and style.

It's the same reason we shouldn't be using the `<font>` tag, `<blink>` tag, `style` attribute, `align` attribute, etc.

Comment: why cant we use style attribute, I don't think there is anything wrong in that

Comment: `size` was originally not purely presentational, but your point stands anyway.

Comment: Same goes for `rows` and `cols`. I disagree though about the use of the `style` attribute. Forbid it and HTML documents will become more unreadable, with `class` attributes all over the place for the specific purpose of assigning style properties. I prefer the more straightforward `style` attribute in those cases. Oh, and by the way, don't mention the _you know what_ element again. According to the W3C, it doesn't exist, and let's keep it that way, OK?

Comment: @Mike If I have a bunch of CSS that needs to be applied to every image, then in the CSS file I can do this real simply by just setting `img { //styles }`, if I was to use the `style` attribute instead, then I would have to set `style="//styles"` on every single image in the document. Changing styles would become very tedious, as I would have to make the same change on every such element.

Comment: @MrLister see previous comment.

Comment: You don't understand. My complaint was in fact the reverse: at one point the W3C proposed to remove the style attribute and even the <style> element, leaving only the external .css files. Then you would only be able to assign styles to specific elements by giving them a class or an id, and putting the styles in the .css file. I wouldn't like that at all!

Comment: @MrLister I get what you're saying now. I do like the `<style>` element. It definitely has a purpose in life (reducing http requests), but I don't use the `style` attribute. IMO it's inefficient, and inconsistent.